# Ignore updates caused by action dispatched from the same component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jointjs

Is there some library, design pattern or way, which would enable to ignore React component updates caused by actions which were dispatched from the same component?

**More details:**

What I am doing now:

```
class Canvas extends Component {
  onNodeMove(){ // Called by JointJS
    this.ignoreAction = true; // Set the ignore flag
    this.props.onNodeMove(node); // Dispatch the action
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(){
    if(this.ignoreAction){ // One-time only ignore
      this.ignoreAction = false;
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
      this.graph.fromJSON(); // Expensive operation
  }
}
```

What I would like to achieve:

```
class Canvas extends Component {
  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (...did the update originated from other component?...) {
      this.graph.fromJSON(this.props.graph); // Reload graph - Expensive operation
    }
  }
}
```

I have one highly complex component named Canvas, which wraps SVG canvas and serves as Graph editor (I use JointJS library for handling the drawing). It handles everything from moving/adding/deleting/selecting nodes, panning, zooming etc...

As the editor I am working on, supports tabs I need to have mirrored the Canvas state into Redux state, so the Canvas can be reloaded with new state coming from Redux, when the tabs are changed. The Canvas state is stored in Redux as object, which can become rather big, but the main problem is passing this object back to JointJS, since its parsing and rerendering it to SVG canvas, is rather costly operation. Every event in the Canvas component (moved node, zooming, panning etc) needs to be dispatched to Redux, but that also means that the component will be updated and the JointJS reloaded, which is something I would like to avoid, since the changes are already present in the SVG canvas.

So far what I am doing is that I set a flag in the component (`ignoreAction`) before dispatching the action and then in `shouldComponentUpdate` I ignore only one action and then I will be receiving all other changes. But I really don't like this approach, because I am pretty sure that it will explode into my face, since some other action could be created meanwhile and the wrong action would be ignored etc...

I was trying to figure out way how to implement this, but so far I really think that the only way is somehow to ignore the actions originated from the component (eq. filtering the update of component based on the origin of the action).

Maybe I have some architecture issue since I came up with this problem, if you think so, please let me know.

*Edit:* Another problem is that any change in the Canvas component needs to be propagated "immediately" to other components.

Comment: A lot of letters, and so little code.

Comment: Well yes, but this is more a concept question, then a specific code related question. I could post here the Canvas code, but I don't think that would help you to understand anything...Did you read the question? What code would you like to have posted here?

Comment: I would only dispatch actions within the component when you are leaving the component itself (componentWillUnmount, for example).

Comment: @DiogoSgrillo so if I understand it correctly, you would extract the component state and dispatch it on componentWillUnmount? That is actually pretty smart, I haven't think of that possibility. But unfortunately it is not possible for me to use, because on the Canvas state (on the graph data) are depending also other components and basically any change in Canvas needs to be propagated to them immediately...

Comment: Well, in this case I suppose you have a poor design of your store. I would have an object like: { canvas: {prop1: value}, otherComponent: {prop1: otherValue}}. When an action is dispatched, you now know which component dispatched. In the mapStateToProps of canvas, you would only consider the values which comes from otherComponent.